# MySQL - How do you enter a record with only whitespace " "?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I want to enter the record with white-space as a record in MySQL. I had tried to enter it through shell and phpmyadmin, the record enters but when I try to retrieve the record it returns as null. I had also set the column null = no even then returns nothing.

code is below through shell and php:

```
insert into first_replace(to_replace, with_replace) values(".", " ");
```

Comment: Could you provide a test code (or at least the table desc)?

Comment: Table's show create output is needed here. Varchar strips whitespace so if that is what you have, it is probably stripping this output entirely

Comment: I believe TechieGurl's assertion about trimming whitespace is only applicable to version <= 5.0.x. However whitespace is ignored when doing comparisions.  Meaning where col="abc" will match both "abc" and "abc   ".

Comment: Perhaps you should approach the problem in another way; rather than including white space in your string replacement definition how about storing a setting? E.g. "trim_string" (0 or 1) (false / true) etc.

Answer (score 4):

You should use VARCHAR instead of CHAR for data type, if you want to store spaces. Space (whitespace) retention is documented in [MySQL online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html):

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are similar, but differ in the way they are
>   stored and retrieved. They also differ in maximum length and in
>   **whether trailing spaces are retained**.

Comment: VARCHAR should keep your whitespaces. Just confirmed on MySQL version 5.1.56.